# Not finding any directory

Tags: php

When using PHP require_once it's not finding the specified directory.
Made sure multiple times this directory does exist!

Also tried this with include. What's the problem here?

File structure:
http://prntscr.com/hut7f0

Code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class main
{

  public static
         $test;
}

require_once '/engine/test.class.php';


main::$test = new Test();
 ?>
```

Error:

```
Warning: require_once(/engine/test.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\loader.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/engine/test.class.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\loader.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be due to usage of an absolute path (path starting with `/`). PHP then tries to find the file at the root of your filesystem. I guess you want to use a relative path here:

```
require_once 'engine/test.class.php';
```

You can use the `__FILE__` constant to get the base path of your current file:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/engine/test.class.php';
```